# GSON parsing for changing json data

Tags: java, json, gson

I am parsing a JSON data using GSON library and the issue what I am facing is, a part of my json data keeps changing below is how my JSON data looks.

```
  {
    "body": [{
        "result": [
        {
            "EndTime": "1411495899000",
            "StartTime": "1411495360000"
        },
        {
            "EndTime": "1411495359000",
            "StartTime": "1411494784000"
        }],
        "rule": {
            "ruleid": "73B5EEB4"
        }
    },
    {
        "result": [
        {
            "noOfErrors": "5",
            "severity": "high"
        },
        {
            "noOfErrors": "4",
            "severity": "low"
        }],
        "rule": {
            "ruleid": "35B5EEB4"
        }
    }
    ],
    "header": {
        "contentver": "5.5"
    }
}
```

So in the above JSON data the **result** array content keeps changing based on the **ruleid** and I want to choose the java bean for **result** content at runtime based on the  **ruleid**. Any idea?

-Regards

Comment: Why can't you just put all 4 fields in your `Result` class and then when reading through it after parsing from JSON, you look either at `end/startTime` or `noOfErrors/severity` based on the `ruleguid`?

Comment: Thanks @Dan, that's what I'm currently doing in my code but as the number of rules increases there will be lot more checks and lot more variables with null values in the beans, so was just looking for a more cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is going to be a long answer ...

You could use a custom `JsonDeserializer` to deserialize the variable part of the json string based on the `ruleid`.

```
public class MessageAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Message> {

    private Map<String, Class<? extends Result>> ruleToResultClassMap;

    public MessageAdapter() {
        this.ruleToResultClassMap = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Result>>();
        ruleToResultClassMap.put("73B5EEB4", DurationResults.class);
        ruleToResultClassMap.put("35B5EEB4", ErrorResults.class);
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public Message deserialize(JsonElement json, java.lang.reflect.Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject messageObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray bodyArray = messageObject.getAsJsonArray("body");

        List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
        for (JsonElement bodyElement : bodyArray) {
            JsonObject resultObject = bodyElement.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonObject ruleObject = resultObject.getAsJsonObject("rule");
            String ruleId = ruleObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("ruleid").getAsString();
            Class<? extends Result> resultClass = ruleToResultClassMap.get(ruleId);
            if (resultClass != null) {
                Result result = context.deserialize(resultObject, resultClass);
                results.add(result);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal ruleId: " + ruleId);
            }
        }
        return new Message(results, context.<Header>deserialize(messageObject.getAsJsonObject("header"), Header.class));
    }
}
```

You need to register the custom deserializer with `GsonBuilder`:

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Message.class, new MessageAdapter());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    String jsonString = null; // your json string
    Message message = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Message.class);
```

Here `Message` is the root POJO of the json string, you probably have your own. For full reference, I include all classes here:

```
public class Message {

    private List<? extends Result> body;
    private Header header;

    public Message(List<? extends Result> body, Header header) {
        this.body = body;
        this.header = header;
    }


    public List<? extends Result> getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public Header getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

}

public class Header {
    private String contentver;

    public Header(String contentVer) {
        this.contentver = contentVer;
    }

    public String getContentVer() {
        return contentver;
    }
}

public interface Result {    
    public Rule getRule();    
}

public final class Rule {
    private String ruleid;

    public String getRuleid() {
        return ruleid;
    }
}

public class DurationResults implements Result {
    private Duration[] result;
    private Rule rule;

    public Duration[] getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Rule getRule() {
        return rule;
    }

    public static final class Duration {
        private long EndTime;
        private long StartTime;

        public long getStartTime() {
            return StartTime;
        }

        public long getEndTime() {
            return EndTime;
        }
    }
}

public class ErrorResults implements Result {    
    private Error[] result;
    private Rule rule;

    public Error[] getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Rule getRule() {
        return rule;
    }

    public static final class Error {
        private int noOfErrors;
        private String severity;

        public int getNoOfErrors() {
            return noOfErrors;
        }

        public String getSeverity() {
            return severity;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: revisiting this question again, after implementing the above approach I am finding my parser is running little slow, any ideas to optimize this parsing and increase the performance?

Comment: @willsteel: to be honest, I am not a `GSON` expert, so I can not help, the only idea is to profile it, if you have not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to parse your json if your result change.

Replace first "result" to "FirstResult" , and replace second "result" to "SecondResult".

Your json have to look like this:

```
{
    "body": [{
        "FirstResult": [
        {
            "EndTime": "1411495899000",
            "StartTime": "1411495360000"
        },
        {
            "EndTime": "1411495359000",
            "StartTime": "1411494784000"
        }],
        "rule": {
            "ruleid": "73B5EEB4"
        }
    },
    {
        "SecondResult": [
        {
            "noOfErrors": "5",
            "severity": "high"
        },
        {
            "noOfErrors": "4",
            "severity": "low"
        }],
        "rule": {
            "ruleid": "35B5EEB4"
        }
    }
    ],
    "header": {
        "contentver": "5.5"
    }
}
```

And you can parse json to Java Objects. If you have first result parse to FirstResultObject.java , if you have second result parse to SecondResult.java

SecondResult.java

```
public class SecondResult
{
    private String noOfErrors;

    private String severity;

    public String getNoOfErrors ()
    {
        return noOfErrors;
    }

    public void setNoOfErrors (String noOfErrors)
    {
        this.noOfErrors = noOfErrors;
    }

    public String getSeverity ()
    {
        return severity;
    }

    public void setSeverity (String severity)
    {
        this.severity = severity;
    }
}
```

FirstResult.java

```
public class FirstResult
{
    private String EndTime;

    private String StartTime;

    public String getEndTime ()
    {
        return EndTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime (String EndTime)
    {
        this.EndTime = EndTime;
    }

    public String getStartTime ()
    {
        return StartTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime (String StartTime)
    {
        this.StartTime = StartTime;
    }
}
```